# how to parse json array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse something like this

```
{
"popular result":[
    {"term":"Summer","url":"http://summer.com"},
    {"term":"Autumn","url":"http://autumn.com"},
    {"term":"spring","url":"http://spring.com/"},
    {"term":"winter","url":"http://winter.com/"}]
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON('/Controls/GetPopularSearches', function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                $.each(myJson.i, function (key, value) {
                    alert(value.term);
                });​
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

but nothing happened! Because is array in array! Please let me know how to do this

Comment: Where does that `myJson` variable come from?

Comment: What's `myJson` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and objects are different things.  You will want to investigate them tons more before things get *really* challenging.

Assuming `json` really does equal the *object* you provide (in JSON those show up as `{}`), then `json['popular result']` (you could use a `.` if there wasn't a space) is the array (in JSON those show up at `[]`) you want to traverse.

For some reason, this confusion got you looping over an object (not going to get you anywhere as `length` is rarely defined for it) and then (ignoring the typo on `myJson`), you started looping over something that didn't exist (which didn't crash b/c it never got there).

Cleaning it up...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Controls/GetPopularSearches', function (json) {
            for (var i=0;i<json['popular result'].length;i++) {
                alert(json['popular result'][i].term + ' points to the URL ' + json['popular result'][i].url);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Notice how the alert references the `json` object (that's your variable name), the `popular result` array, then `[i]` is the "row" in that array, and the `term/url` element of the object on that row.

NOTE: Running something with a ton of alerts as you're debugging is annoying.  Check out `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$.each` and you need to loop over the array set as the value of `popular result` which is inside a containing object.

```
$.getJSON('/Controls/GetPopularSearches', function (json) {
  var arr = json['popular result'];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].term);
  }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kRy3/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle

```
var jsontext =
    '{"popularresult":[{"term":"Summer","url":"http://summer.com"},{"term":"Summer","url":"http://summer.com"}]}';
var getContact = JSON.parse(jsontext);

for (i = 0; i < getContact.popularresult.length; i++) {
    alert(getContact.popularresult[i].term);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ae8gd/

Answer (score -2):

If you get the jsonObject as shown then

```
 var JsonArray=json.popular; //get jsonArry
 $.each(JsonArray,function(i,val){
 // do logic
 });
```

To parse json use JSON.parse();

Comment: No. There is really NO reason to use [`evil()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx). Don't suggest `evil()`, don't even think about `evil()`. And don't, for god's sake, don't misspell `evil()` as `eval()`. `JSON.parse()` is native JS by the way. It has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Disclaimer: Don't take my previous comment too seriously, by the way. Just giving some suggestions __;-)__ Downvote removed.